# Hardware crashed, Bitcoin core won’t load

Tags: json-rpc, linux

I can’t believe this hasn’t come up multiple times.

My hardware crashed (actually locked up and could only be unlocked by a forced (unplug) power off) while Bitcoin core was running. Of course on restart various files will/can not load. Specifically (it seems) settings.json.

Tried to delete the entire Bitcoin-23.0 file but permission denied.

Running Ubuntu OS.

Comment: What does it tell, when trying to start Bitcoin?

Comment: Settings file could not be written.  (New Paragraph) A fatal error occurred. Check that settings file is writeable, or try running with -nosettings.  <<Show Detail . . .>> " - Error: Unable to open settings file /[path]/Bitcoin/settings.json.tmp for writing"

Comment: interesting data directory, where did you get that software copy? you can work around the problem by solving the permissions problem you pasted

Comment: I manually set up the directory because that's where the blocks were stored (from a prior install). My question is HOW to "solve" the permissions problem.